# Ways to examine models/objects in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently looking through a system trying to figure out how things work together - I know a couple basic ways to examine objects (I'm in the console), such as Object.methods, but I was wondering if there were ways to find, say, it's attributes, and it's relationships with other models (for example, has_many relationships) and the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pry gem is awesome for this sort of thing.

Dig [this Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails).

Comment: I was wondering what that "pry" thing in front of my console was! Someone actually just walked by and commented on it, but I had no idea what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're referring to specifically an ActiveRecord object. If you look up the documentation on ActiveRecord (e.g., http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), you'll find a lot of methods to get some useful info. For example, to see the attributes, you could examine MyActiveRecord.attribute_names.